# C#: Receive incoming mail sent to myaddress@mydomain.com

Tags: c#, email

I have my own (Windows) VServer with my own domain and mx record.
Now I want to build a simple mail listener, which listens to all incoming mail to "*@mydomain.com" and stores it in a database.

I spent probably an hour googling, searching stackoverflow and informing about protocols, but I haven't found anything quite close to what I want to achieve.

What I don't want to do:

- Receive mails via IMAP/POP3/Exchange from an existing mailbox server
- Send Mails via SMTP
- Install any mailbox server software, e.g. Mercury Mail

Comment: Services like MailGun will do this for you.

Comment: @SLaks: MailGun has a nice API, but is not quite what I am looking for as it is a platform and not only a library.

Comment: Running a mail server is not an easy task.